# How can I use gotoAndStop() in a custom class "Game"?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a class `Game` in which I have a variable `pointsCount` to count the points, which starts with 0 in constructor.

```
//my Game class

package 

{
public var pointsCount:Number;
public static const status_begin:int = 1;

public function Game {}
{
    pointsCount = 0;
}
```

Then I have a function `points()` to handle the points:

```
public function points():void
        {
            if(ball.randomIndex == 0)
            {
            pointsCount++;
            }
            if(ball.randomIndex == 1)
            {
            pointsCount--;
            }
                        ....
               }
```

Then I have a function to change level:

```
public function changeLevel():void
        {
                if(pointsCount == 4)
                {
                    statusGame(4);

                }

                else if(pointsCount == 8) 
                {
                    statusGame(5);


                }
```

And I have my `statusGame` function to "control" the game status:

```
public function statusGame(status:int):void
        {
            switch(status)
            {
                case 1:
                this.startGame();
                break; 

                case 2: 
               ballBroken = false;
                ball = newBall(this,velX,velY);
                break;

                case 3:                 
                ballBroken = true;
                points();
                break;

                case 4: trace("Level 2") ;
                velX = 15;
                velY = -2;

                break;

                case 5:trace("Level 3") ;
                velX = 18;
                velY = -2;

                break;
```

My function to start the game which is called in status 1 (case 1):

```
public function startGame():void
        {
            ball = new Ball(this,10,-4);
        }
```

I also have a .fla document where I have my game scenery and actions frame with this code:

```
import Game;

game.gameStatus(Game.status_begin); //to start the game

**if(Game.pointsCount)
{
 trace("points 10");
 **game.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _enterFrame);**
 gotoAndStop(3);

}**
```

I import my class `Game` then I create an object to access my function `gameStatus` to start the game.

Now when the points are equal to 10 I want to use `gotoAndStop(3)` method to go to the frame 3.

However, my `pointsCount` variable is always 0, because in my `Game` constructor I declared `pointsCount = 0`. I want to access `pointsCount` when it is equal to 10; how can I do that?

I think the problem is because I handle `pointsCount` inside my function `changeLevel()`. How can I access this variable in my .fla document? I'm trying to solve this but nothing works..

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're attempting to go to frame 3 when your pointsCount reaches 10?  You're treating a number like a boolean, which is valid code, but may not be what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some basic syntax errors in your code, but I assume they're just in the question, and your actual code is compiling fine.

The problem seems to be that you're only checking for pointsCount to change one time.  There are a couple of ways you can fix that, either by doing your check in the main timeline every frame, or by handling custom events that are fired off from your game class itself.

The first method is by far the easiest, if not quite as elegant as the latter. Try leaving your internal code the same (fixing any syntax errors that might exist)

```
public var pointsCount:Number;
public static const status_begin:int = 1;

//Constructor
public function Game()
{
    pointsCount = 0;
}

//points incrementing and decrementing
public function points():void
{
    if(ball.randomIndex == 0)
    {
        pointsCount++;
    }
    if(ball.randomIndex == 1)
    {
        pointsCount--;
    }

    //Other code.
}

//Changing the level.
public function changeLevel():void
{
    if(pointsCount == 4)
    {
        statusGame(4);
    }

    else if(pointsCount == 8) 
    {
        statusGame(5);
    }
}
```

Then rewrite your check on the main timeline to repeat every frame.

```
import Game;
import flash.events.*;

//make a new game.
var game:Game = new Game();
//Add an event listener for each frame.
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkScore);

//Start the game.
game.statusGame(Game.status_begin);

//Check when points equal 10.
function checkScore(e:Event)
{
    if(game.pointsCount == 10)
    {
     trace("points 10");
     gotoAndStop(3);

    }
}
```

Depending on what you want to happen with your game, you may find it necessary to stop checking the points value after you move to frame 3.  You can remove an event listener with `this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkScore);`

Comment: Thank you very much, i didnt thought in that, sure i had to use the enter frame to always be always checking if the pointsCount already reached the 10 points. But now i have other problem that its: in the frame 3 i dont have any code in actions because its my end game frame. But dont know why the balls in my game continue to enter the stage.

Comment: :) In actionscript, references persist between frames.  It's intended (I believe) to allow easy access of variables from different places in your project.  

What that means is that if you have any events being fired off on one frame, going to another frame won't stop those events from firing off.  You can fix that by adding on frame 3 the code above `this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkScore);`  I don't know how you're updating your game, but you should probably remove that listener as well - maybe `game.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, yourFunction);`?

Comment: thank you very much, now i get it (the logic) :)! But when i do this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkScore); everything is ok, but when i do "game.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _enterFrame);" i got an error "Acess of undefined property _enterFrame. I think its because i have my game enter frame in a class Game and its not "visible" or "acessible" in my frame 3. The "this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkScore);" works finebecause this function checkScore is in frame 1 and how you said references persist between frames.

Comment: You're absolutely correct about the accessibility of functions within Game, it was silly of me not to think of it before.  The best way to get around this is to have a method within the game class that will remove all the events tied to it.  Something like - `public function cleanup() { this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _enterFrame); }`  Then on frame 3 you can just call `game.cleanup();`.

Comment: As a complete side note, the reason that it's not a great idea to do all of that cleanup in the update loop of your Game class itself as opposed to calling it on frame 3 is because Actionscript is very 'sticky' with its references.  If you remove an event while one it's being fired off - in this case, removing the enterFrame event before `_enterframe` finishes, Actionscript will happily remove the event, and then as soon as the function finishes executing, just as happily add it right back on again.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your clearly explanation! Now i dont have that error "Acess of undefined property" and my game stops so i think its ok but when i do a trace(game.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _enterFrame)); it appears undefined, its normal?

Comment: Should be normal, removeEventListener doesn't return anything. If it's stopped though, it seems like everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add pointsCount as a public variable in your class Game like below to access it from outside.

package
    {

```
public static const status_begin:int = 1;
public var pointsCount:Number;
public function Game {}
{
    pointsCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i already have that, and pointsCount its always 0 in my .fla document actions!

Comment: Its not possible also call the method gotoAndStop(3); in my class game? Im trying but i gon an error, "call to possibly undefined method gotoAndStop

Comment: try this (root as MovieClip).gotoAndStop(3)

Comment: i got an error, TypeError: Error #1009: Can not access a property or method of a null object reference.